# Foundation 5 range sliders not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

I created a site with 4 calculators with Foundation 5 range slider and I started running cross browser tests and found out that internet explorer doesn't working at all: ![IE 8][1]

Also there no value in the input in IE9- IE11 and current version of Firefox. How can I fix this issue? ![IE9][2]

This is the site [itself][3]

How can I make it work across internet explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Foundation 5 [doesn't support IE 8](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html) at all but you can try [this](http://www.kycosoftware.com/blog/article/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8).

Quoted from [Foundation FAQ](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html):

> **Why doesn't Foundation support IE7 or IE8? Or: why we don't support a dying species.**
>
> This is probably the biggest question we get. Consider this: most of
>   today's popular browsers automatically upgrade themselves including
>   Chrome, Firefox and Explorer (starting with 9). IE 8 is the last IE
>   supported on Windows XP, which Microsoft will officially stop
>   supporting next year. That played a part in our decision.
>
> Besides that, since Foundation 4, our framework is built mobile-first,
>   meaning it relies on media queries to layer in more complex layouts
>   and components. Browsers or devices that don't support media queries
>   will be restricted to a simple, single-column layout. In some ways,
>   Foundation 4 better supports IE6-7 insomuch as it provides a mobile
>   but not entirely broken experience. If IE8 support is important for
>   your users / customers, you can use Foundation 3.2, which supports
>   IE8. It's not mobile first but it's good stuff.